# Assignment in controller is not passing through to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My assignment `$scope.getForecastByLocation`in the controller is not being passed through to the controller. Currently `city`is specified to random city like "Berkeley", and this city is passed to the factory Data. But the idea is that when the user types a new city in the input, it takes the input and sends a new city parameter to the Data factory.

I've been doing console.logs and I can see that the button is working but calling `Data.getApps($scope.inputcity);` is not working and thus the city is always in "Berkeley".

Can anyone figure out why I can't send a new city to the Data factory? Thank you!

index.html

```
 <input ng-model="city">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="getForecastByLocation(city)">SUBMIT</md-button>
```

controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('weatherApp.controllers', [])

    var city = 'Berkeley';

    app.controller('weatherCtrl', ['$scope','Data',

        function($scope, Data) {
        $scope.getForecastByLocation = function(city) {
                $scope.inputcity = city;
                console.log($scope.inputcity);
                Data.getApps($scope.inputcity).then(function(data){
                    $scope.data = data;
                    $scope.name = data.name;
                    console.log($scope.data); //object shows "Berkeley"
                    console.log($scope.name);
                 });//initiate Data.getApps by passing in a new city
         }
        Data.getApps(city).then(function(data) {
          $scope.data = data;

          var vm = $scope;

          vm.description = data.weather[0].description;
          vm.speed = (2.237 * data.wind.speed).toFixed(1) + " mph";
          vm.name = data.name;
          vm.humidity = data.main.humidity + " %";
          vm.temp = data.main.temp;
          vm.fTemp = (vm.temp * (9 / 5) - 459.67).toFixed(1) + " °F";

        },function(res) {
            if(res.status === 500) {
                // server error, alert user somehow
            } else { 
                // probably deal with these errors differently
            }
        }

        ); // end of function

    }])//end of controller
```

service.js

```
app.factory('Data', function($http, $q) {

    var data = [],
       lastRequestFailed = true,
       promise;
   return {
      getApps: function(city) {
         if(!promise || lastRequestFailed) {
            // $http returns a promise, so we don't need to create one with $q

            promise = $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?',{
              params: {
                q: city,
              }
            })
            .then(function(res) {
                lastRequestFailed = false;
                data = res.data;
                return data;
            }, function(res) {
                return $q.reject(res);
            });
         }
         return promise;
      }
   }
});
```

EDIT:

I modified my controller code a bit from other people's suggestion and it currently looks like this. The factory is the same and I have deleted the parameter in the HTML.

```
app.controller('weatherCtrl', ['$scope','Data',

    function($scope, Data) {
$scope.city = 'Berkeley';

$scope.getForecastByLocation = function() {
                console.log($scope.city); //making sure I can read the input
                console.log('this is your input ' + $scope.city);
                Data.getApps($scope.city).then(function(data){
                console.log('this is your output ' + $scope.city); //should say "This is your output "tracy", but it still reads at "Berkeley"

                    $scope.data = data;
                    $scope.name = data.name;
                    console.log($scope.data); //object shows "Berkeley"
                    console.log($scope.name);
                 });//initiate Data.getApps by passing in a new city
         }
```

[image]

Comment: ngclick => ng-click ?

Comment: Oh that's a copy and paste error. In my actual code it actually is ng-click.

Comment: Get the city value by `$scope.city` rather than pass the **city** parameter.

Comment: Are you talking about in the html? Should the Data factory parameter change too then? Also are you talking about `$scope.inputcity`? I dont see specifically see a `$scope.city`

Comment: Using `ng-model="city"` will create two-way binding with `$scope.city`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('weatherApp.controllers', [])

    var city = 'Berkeley'; 

    app.controller('weatherCtrl', ['$scope','Data',

        function($scope, Data) {
        $scope.getForecastByLocation = function() {
                $scope.inputcity = $scope.city;
                console.log($scope.inputcity);
                Data.getApps($scope.inputcity).then(function(data){
                    $scope.data = data;
                    $scope.name = data.name;
                    console.log($scope.data); //object shows "Berkeley"
                    console.log($scope.name);
                 });//initiate Data.getApps by passing in a new city
         }
        Data.getApps(city).then(function(data) {
          $scope.data = data;

          var vm = $scope;

          vm.description = data.weather[0].description;
          vm.speed = (2.237 * data.wind.speed).toFixed(1) + " mph";
          vm.name = data.name;
          vm.humidity = data.main.humidity + " %";
          vm.temp = data.main.temp;
          vm.fTemp = (vm.temp * (9 / 5) - 459.67).toFixed(1) + " °F";

        },function(res) {
            if(res.status === 500) {
                // server error, alert user somehow
            } else { 
                // probably deal with these errors differently
            }
        }

        ); // end of function

    }]);
    app.factory('Data', function($http, $q) {

    var data = [],
       lastRequestFailed = true,
       promise;
   return {
      getApps: function(city) {
         if(!promise || lastRequestFailed) {
            // $http returns a promise, so we don't need to create one with $q

            promise = $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?',{
              params: {
                q: city,
              }
            })
            .then(function(res) {
                lastRequestFailed = false;
                data = res.data;
                promise = false; // reset the promise value.
                return data;
            }, function(res) {
                return $q.reject(res);
            });
         }
         return promise;
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="weatherApp.controllers">
    <div ng-controller="weatherCtrl">
        <input ng-model="city">
        <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="getForecastByLocation()">SUBMIT</md-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but i'm having a hard time understanding `$scope.inputcity = $scope.city;`. If I understand correctly, the input will now be stored as `$scope.inputcity` and that's the parameter we pass to Data factory. What's the point of setting that to $scope.city? Also, I've tried your method but the object is still coming out as Berkeley :(

Comment: The API is not working for me. The reason is that you are not reset the `promise`, the promise is always the first request promise.

Comment: I took away the api key and I know that's why it's not running. Should I place it in? And how can I reset the `promise`?

Comment: I already updated my code. You can try first. 
`lastRequestFailed = false;
data = res.data;
promise = false; // reset the promise value.
return data;` 
In the `getApps` function.

Comment: Pay attention: when the promise is reject, you should reset the values, too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your controller is trying to assign `$scope.inputcity` to the value of `var city = 'Berkeley` instead of assigning it to the value of the function argument `city`. It is best practice to avoid using the same name for a variable accessible from the function's scope and the function's argument.

Instead of passing `city` as an argument for `ng-click="getForecastByLocation(city)"`, why not just access `$scope.city` directly in your controller?

Your function could look like this:

```
$scope.getForecastByLocation = function() {
            console.log($scope.city);
            Data.getApps($scope.city).then(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.name = data.name;
                console.log($scope.data); //object shows "Berkeley"
                console.log($scope.name);
             });
     }
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is such a basic question, but i just want to really clarify my understanding for angularjs. So if that's the case, then in the HTML, there is no parameter it would just be `ng-click = getForecastByLocation()` right? Then in the factory, would its parameters be `$scope.city` too?

Comment: Correct, you would not need a parameter for `getForecastByLocation()` in your html. I would recommend setting a default value like `$scope.city = 'Berkeley';` in your controller so that you no longer have a `city` variable causing confusion with your function parameter name. I do not think you would need to make a change to the factory, especially since it is not accessing `$scope`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried your method I'm still getting the output as "Berkeley" even though I'm trying to change the city. If you look at my edit above, you can see that I typed in "Tokyo" and it reads Tokyo as `$scope.city`, but for some reason it's not passing through as an argument in the factory. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Yes, your factory is not changing the value of `$scope.city`. I may need to take a closer look at what your factory is doing, but at a glance I can see that you would need to assign `$scope.city` to the `data` being passed back from `Data.getApps()` to change its value.